# HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available(Camunda)

Tags: hikaricp, camunda, camunda-modeler

After upgrade from camunda **7.8 to 7.9** i am getting this HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available , can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:667)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:183)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:148)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:262)
```

--

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:305)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.handleExistingTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:430)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:354)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.DbIdGenerator.getNewBlock(DbIdGenerator.java:46)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.DbIdGenerator.getNextId(DbIdGenerator.java:38)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.ensureHasId(DbEntityManager.java:663)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.entitymanager.DbEntityManager.insert(DbEntityManager.java:546)
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to increase the pool size & looks like this exception has gone.

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useSSL=false'
        username: root
        password: pass
        driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        hikari:
            minIdle: 10
            idle-timeout: 10000
            maximumPoolSize: 30
```

These are the following configuration changes we can do on hikari, please add/update according to your need.

```
autoCommit
connectionTimeout
idleTimeout
maxLifetime
connectionTestQuery
connectionInitSql
validationTimeout
maximumPoolSize
poolName
allowPoolSuspension
readOnly
transactionIsolation
leakDetectionThreshold
```